# Ionic & Capacitor - ...\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\libs (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, build.gradle, capacitor, fastlane

When generated a Android App Bundle, I do get the following

```
 ...\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\libs (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I gave a look at the `capacitor-cordova-android-plugins` folder and this is what I have.

[image]

Does somebody have an Idea why the `libs` folder does not exists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was coming from a code I had added into my `Fastfile` config.

```
platform :android do
  desc "Build the app and send it to Google Play for testing"

  before_all do
    gradle(
      task: "clean",
      project_dir: 'android/'
    )
  end

  lane :build do
```

I was cleaning the android directory, which removed the required file.